# React hook not working when page is wrapped in a 100vh element

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-hooks, use-effect, parallax

This might be very specific but I am pulling my hair for over a week so I have to ask.

*** edit: i re-produced this bug (?) in codesandbox so you can check it yourselves:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-51r5n
(the button is just to add/remove a class to the parallax-wrapper component to easily show the differences)

---

*** edit2: i believe it has something to do with the following:
in App.js, there are 2 components, the Nav-component and the ParaWrapper-component. I believe, because I give the ParaWrapper a height of 100vh, the Nav has technically no height left (?). I still can see the Nav in the element inspector, and if i manually add the fade-in class, it works as intended. Maybe this is a clue for someone to solve this riddle?

---

Situation: react hooks are not working. My page consists of a parallax (scss only) hero section (2 layers, 1 base layer and 1 back layer), followed by a couple other regular sections.
More specific: in my navbar component i use useeffect to determine if i already have scrolled for > 50 pixels, and if so, removes and adds classes to my navbar to show/hide it with an animation.
It took a while for me to find out what caused the problem, but it seems that when I remove (or out-comment) the height of the para-wrapper component, the navbar animation is working as intended (useeffect hook is working), but the parallax-effect will stop working.

I've tried with useState hook as well but it's the same issue; set navbar classes won't work when height is set (and works when not set, but then again losing the parallax effect).

In element inspector i can see the classes are NOT applied properly when the height: 100vh is active on the para-wrapper, but it DOES work when the height is removed (which means the code works, but somehow it's being blocked).

- edited this question and deleted all the code in here as i added a viewable project so you can work with it *

Thanks a lot for taking a look, I hope some of you can find the issue here. Regards

Comment: That sure is a lot of code. Are you sure this is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? 

Anyway, it looks like you're only selecting the nav element on first render in Nav. Once React updates the DOM, that element (and its listener) will go away and a new one will be inserted (without the listener). I suspect that's the root of your problem.

Comment: Would this topic be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768695/image-with-parallax-effect-on-full-screen-page-without-scrollbars

Comment: @samuei the code works as intended when i turn the height of the parallax wrapper off (it worked perfectly before i implemented the parallax effect). i am only selecting the nav element (and it's children) because that element is the one i want to unhide/hide when scrolling on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question! Finally. What pointed me in the right direction what the answer on this topic:

[Not getting callback after adding an event listener for scroll event in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207398/not-getting-callback-after-adding-an-event-listener-for-scroll-event-in-react-js)

The complete answer consists of a couple of fixes.
First , I had to move the eventlistener from the Nav component to the Hero component (duh, otherwise it would only listen when scrolling on the Nav component).
Second, instead of using **window**.addEventListener, i had to use the element on which i was scrolling (so in this case, a variable which refered to the **para-wrapper** element).
Lastly, window.scrollY always remained at 0, so i had to change window.scrollY here as well to (variable with reference to the para-wrapper element).scroll**Top**!